# Silverlight / WPF Binding Nested Objects

Tags: wpf, silverlight, data-binding

Instance of  MyViewModel is set as DataContext of the .Xaml file. Data is bound as below, but the Text for {FName1, FName2, LName1, LName2} are not getting displayed. Only the Text for (ThePerson) is getting displayed. Appreciate if any one have a suggestion to fix it.

### .xaml file

```
<StackPanel> 
    <TextBlock x:Name="ThePerson" Text="{Binding PersonOne}" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="FName1" Text="{Binding PersonOne.FirstName}" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="FName2" Text="{Binding Person.FirstName}" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="LName1" Text="{Binding Path=PersonOne.LastName}" />
    <TextBlock x:Name="LName2" Text="{Binding Path=Person.LastName}" />
</StackPanel>
```

### ViewModel file

```
public class MyViewModel {
    public MyViewModel()
    {
        PersonOne = new Person()
        {
            FirstName = "James",
            LastName = "San"
        };
    }
    public Person PersonOne { get; set; }
}

public class Person {
    public string FirstName;
    public string LastName;
    public override string ToString()
    {
        return string.Format("{0}, {1}", LastName, FirstName);
    }
}
```

Comment: WPF and Silverlight are very different beasts.  Which is it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to make the FirstName, etc as properties of the Person class instead of fields. Add a getter and setter to them. You can only bind to properties.